# C# WPF export Table to CSV

Tags: c#, tablerow, tablecell

C# WPF, How to export Table to CSV? It is neither DataTable nor DataGrid. It's just a c# Table and I need that only for my code. pls refer screenshot and pls give your suggestions

[c#table using xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlKs2.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: thank u for your comment. I have tried to clone the source document using xaml writer and xml reader but it doesn't work.